# Why __exit__ is not executed when __enter__ raises exception

Tags: python, contextmanager

I was wondering lately what was the reason behind not calling implicitly `__exit__` when `__enter__` raises exception? 
Why it was designed in such way? I was implementing service runner class to be usable by `'with'` keyword and it turned out that `__exit__` is never called.

Example:

```
class ServiceRunner(object):
    def __init__(self, allocation_success):
        self.allocation_success = allocation_success

    def _allocate_resource(self):
        print("Service1 running...")
        print("Service2 running...")

        # running service3 fails ...
        if not self.allocation_success:
            raise RuntimeError("Service3 failed!")
        print("Service3 running...")

    def _free_resource(self):
        print("All services freed.")

    def __enter__(self):
        self._allocate_resource()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._free_resource()
```

Usage:

```
with ServiceRunner(allocation_success=True):
    pass

try:
    with ServiceRunner(allocation_success=False):
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
Service1 running...
Service2 running...    
Service3 running...
All services freed.
```

and

```
Service1 running...
Service2 running...
Service3 failed!
```

Function `__exit__` is not called. Service1 and Service2 are not freed.

I could move `_allocate_resource()` to `__init__` but then class is not very useful in such usage:

```
try:
    runner = ServiceRunner(allocation_success=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    with runner as r:
        r.do()

    with runner as r:
        r.do()
```

Output:

```
Service1 running...
Service2 running...
Service3 running...
All services freed.
All services freed.
```

Services are not started again.

I could reimplement `__enter__` to handle exceptions but it adds some boilerplate code to the function:

```
def __enter__(self):
    try:
        self._allocate_resource()
    except Exception as e:
        self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
        raise e
```

Is it the best solution?

Comment: Why would `__exit__` be called by default? What happens if I do `with open('file_that_doesn't_exist') as infile:`? There's no resource used, since the file doesn't exist, to be closed down.

Comment: @roganjosh: That's a different case. If the file doesn't exist, then `__enter__` is never even called.

Answer (score 3):

If you've failed to enter a context, there's no reason to attempt to exit it, i.e. if you've failed to allocate a resource, there's no reason to attempt to release it.

IIUC, what you're looking for is simply:

```
try:
   with ServiceRunner() as runner:
       runner.do()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Some resources are already allocated before exception is raised. I want to be sure that they are freed.

Comment: Then your approach to try/catch at `__enter__` is fine; don't feel obliged to use `__exit__`